# ARM compiler with autoconf

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, autotools

I am trying to compile some files for ARM architecture with autoconf. I am compiling them in Ubuntu 12.04 and the target system is a BeagleBoard XM.
I run the following command:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi -prefix=${CSTOOL_DIR}/linux_arm_tool
```

and get this result:

```
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-strip... arm-linux-gnueabi-strip   
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/edgar/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

And here is the config.log file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by commserver configure 3.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --target=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu -prefix=/linux_arm_tool

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ear-it
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.5.0-27-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 26 19:33:56 UTC 2013

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /home/ear-it/Desktop/arm-2008q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin
PATH: /home/ear-it/Desktop/arm-2008q3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1801: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1869: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:1880: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:1930: result: yes
configure:1979: checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
configure:1995: found /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
configure:2006: result: arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
configure:2071: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2110: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2123: checking for gawk
configure:2153: result: no
configure:2123: checking for mawk
configure:2139: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:2150: result: mawk
configure:2161: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2183: result: yes
configure:2272: checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
configure:2288: found /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
configure:2299: result: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
configure:2568: checking for C compiler version
configure:2577: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version >&5
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2588: $? = 0
configure:2577: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.6.3 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-float=softfp --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include --with-headers=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include --with-libs=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
configure:2588: $? = 0
configure:2577: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -V >&5
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2588: $? = 4
configure:2577: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -qversion >&5
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2588: $? = 4
configure:2608: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2630: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O3 -m32 -s -w   conftest.c  >&5
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-m32'
configure:2634: $? = 1
configure:2672: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "commserver"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "commserver"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "commserver 3.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "commserver"
| #define VERSION "3.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2677: error: in `/home/ear-it/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver/build':
configure:2679: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=i686-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-linux-gnueabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=i686-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/ear-it/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/ear-it/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/ear-it/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/ear-it/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='mawk'
CC='arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-O3 -m32 -s -w'
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/ear-it/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver/missing --run makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='commserver'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='commserver'
PACKAGE_STRING='commserver 3.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='commserver'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='arm-linux-gnueabi-strip'
VERSION='3.2'
ac_ct_CC=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=' -I$(srcdir)'
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias='arm-linux-gnueabi'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/ear-it/Desktop/smartsantander/commserver/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/linux_arm_tool'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias='i686-pc-linux-gnu'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "commserver"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "commserver"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "commserver 3.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "commserver"
#define VERSION "3.2"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Can you try just `--host=arm-linux`?  What package, what **autoconf** tools and do you use the `configure` from a tar-ball?

Comment: Doesn't work either. I use **autoconf 2.68**. `configure` is called from the autogen.sh script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `unrecognized command line option '-m32'`.  You don't pass *-m32* to an **ARM** compiler.  This is a most likely a mistake in the package or possibly something you are doing with `configure`.  Remove that from *Makefile.in* or where ever it is in the *package*.

### How to read a *config.log*

The *config.log* is especially un-intuitive when you begin to use it.  There is a large section at the end of the file where `configure` dumps all **variables**.  You have to keep scrolling up until you find the command that actually failed.  Some phrases to search backwards are *Cache variables.* and *See 'config.log' for more details*.  Generally, at this point, some program is shown, compile options and output.  In your example above, this is where you can find the *-m32* being rejected.

Comment: In my case I was using native compiler provided with Tizen SDK. It has no idea where its sysroot is located. To figure this out, I needed to inspect `config.log`.

Then I ran `CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/path/to/sysroot" CXX="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ --sysroot=/path/to/sysroot" ./configure ...`

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=${CSTOOL_DIR}/linux_arm_tool
```

Works for me. I already compiled a lot of libraries that way. My guess is, that the autoconf script of the package you want to build is broken.

Comment: I am trying to compile it in Ubuntu, so I guess my host system should be /usr/bin/gcc 
I run the following command:

    `./configure --build=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi --target=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --host=/usr/bin/gcc -prefix=${CSTOOL_DIR}/linux_arm_tool`

But still the executable says:

    `commserver: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xbf544fb0eacc80f12f8baba9a1a3ac980403c6a3, stripped`

Comment: In my case it was also needed to build is as static.

Comment: It should be: `./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi  --prefix=${CSTOOL_DIR}/linux_arm_tool` (fix missing '-'). I cannot change it due silly stackoverflow.com rules (change more than 6 characters)