# Building ZeroMQ against ucLibc for ARM9 system

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, arm

I am trying to build the hello world server and client examples for ZeroMQ for an ARM9 system.
I can build the examples, but when I try and run them `zmq_connect()` returns `0`, but `errno` is set to `11`, and if I call `zmq_send()`, set to non blocking, -1 is returned and `errno` is set to `11`.

My toolchain is using `ucLibc`.

I have configured the zmq source tree with:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc CXX=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++
```

In the verbose from the configuration I see the following entries which concern me:

```
checking ifaddrs.h usability... no
checking ifaddrs.h presence... no
checking for ifaddrs.h... no
checking sys/eventfd.h usability... no
checking sys/eventfd.h presence... no
checking for sys/eventfd.h... no
```

If I configure for x86 the results for the above checks are "yes".

My question is how do I fix the above issues so that I can use the zero mq on my ARM9 platform?

Kind regards

Andrew Ellis

Comment: This is a basic cross `configure` issue.  You need to point `CC` to use Linux headers by default.  Ie. with `-isystem <path_to_linux>/` or something like that.  Your ARM linux headers will not be in the standard locations when you cross configure and build.  See the tag [tag:cross-compiling] and maybe a [search there with configure](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[cross-compiling]+configure).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I amended my configure command to:

`./configure --host=arm-linux --includedir=/home/user/streamer/mozart_kernel-1.30/include CC=arm-linux-gcc CXX=arm-linux-g++`

But when I run `./configure` I now get the following warnings:

`configure: WARNING: ifaddrs.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: sys/eventfd.h: present but cannot be compiled`

There are more messages relating to the above, but I don't have enough room for this comment. One of my colleagues who has returned from vacation has suggested that how the toochain has not been built correctly.

Comment: See: [ARM compiler with autoconf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188228/arm-compiler-with-autoconf).  This gives advice on how to read the configure logs to see exactly what is wrong.  `configure` tried to compile a test file with `#include "ifaddrs.h"`, but the compile fails.  You can look at the logs to find out exactly why.