# Troubles cross compiling with cgo enabled using go 1.3 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, go, cross-compiling, cgo

I tried to cross compile cgo code to linux/arm on my darwin/amd64 MBP with Go 1.3, but ended with no luck :(

My environment:

`go version go1.3 darwin/amd64`

My goal:

Cross compiling cgo code targeting linux/arm.

Step 1:

Building gcc/g++ cross compiler with ct-ng. It was a long way to build `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++` and `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, but I finally made it. I tested with simple C/C++ programs and the outputs worked fine on my linux/arm R-Pi box.

Step 2:

> cd /path/to/go/src
>
> sudo CGO_ENABLED=1 CC_FOR_TARGET=/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX_FOR_TARGET=/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm ./make.bash

Everything built OK.

Step 3:

Compiling the following simple cgo code:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
"unsafe"
)

func main() {
    str := C.CString("abc\n")
    C.printf(str)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(str))
}
```

For my host machine:

`go install package/of/test`

Failed with

`arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'`

For linux/arm:

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go install package/of/test`

Failed with

> runtime.main: call to external function main.main runtime.main:
>
> undefined: main.main

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188228/arm-compiler-with-autoconf

Comment: are you aware that go 1.3 is EOL ? https://go.dev/doc/devel/release#policy

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem for cross compiling Android on Mac. Hope it help you.

On your step 2:

`sudo CGO_ENABLED=1 CC_FOR_TARGET=/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX_FOR_TARGET=/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm ./make.bash`

add target for RANLIB, something like this (I do not know certain)

`sudo CGO_ENABLED=1 CC_FOR_TARGET=/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX_FOR_TARGET=/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ranlib GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm ./make.bash`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you could try https://github.com/karalabe/xgo.

It makes cross compiling with cgo involved really simple:

- have docker installed and running
- go get github.com/karalabe/xgo
- cd
- xgo --targets=linux/arm .

There are lots of other options on how to compile.