# Build protobuf-c, libprotobuf-c, for mbed LPC1768 arm-none-eabi-g++

Tags: c++, c, embedded, mbed, protobuf-c

I'm trying to build libprotobuf-c for the mbed platfrom but having some issues with the ./configure settings. I think I need more compile flags but am unsure what to include. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
./configure arm-none-eabi --disable-protoc
```

Comment: what error messages do you get?

Comment: configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
... 
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... arm-none-eabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/edward/c/protobuf-c-1.1.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188228/arm-compiler-with-autoconf help?

Answer (score 1):

Just included the protobuf-c.h/c files into my project directly.