# fftw compilation error for ARM cross-compile

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, autotools, fftw

I am trying to cross-compiler FFTW for ARM. My configure command is,

```
./configure --with-slow-timer --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-single --enable-neon "CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp"
```

I have also tried simple ./configure command but got the same error as,

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-strip... arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

the config.log is,

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by fftw configure 3.3.4, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --with-slow-timer --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-single --enable-neon CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp --enable-float CFLAGS=-arch=native

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = junaids-OptiPlex-755
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.13.0-86-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #130-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:27:15 UTC 2016

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2750: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2818: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2829: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2884: result: yes
configure:2943: checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
configure:2959: found /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
configure:2970: result: arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
configure:3035: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3074: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3081: checking for gawk
configure:3111: result: no
configure:3081: checking for mawk
configure:3097: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:3108: result: mawk
configure:3119: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3141: result: yes
configure:3170: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3187: result: yes
configure:3316: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3325: result: no
configure:3373: checking build system type
configure:3387: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:3407: checking host system type
configure:3420: result: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
configure:3818: checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
configure:3845: result: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp
configure:4114: checking for C compiler version
configure:4123: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp --version >&5
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4134: $? = 0
configure:4123: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --disable-libitm --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --with-cloog --enable-cloog-backend=ppl --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv5t --with-float=soft --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1) 
configure:4134: $? = 0
configure:4123: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -V >&5
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4134: $? = 4
configure:4123: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -qversion >&5
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4134: $? = 4
configure:4154: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4176: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -arch=native - L/usr/local/include - L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  >&5
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch=native'
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: L/usr/local/include: No such file or directory
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: L/usr/local/lib: No such file or directory
configure:4180: $? = 1
configure:4218: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fftw"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "fftw 3.3.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "fftw@fftw.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "fftw"
| #define VERSION "3.3.4"
| #define FFTW_ENABLE_ALLOCA 1
| #define FFTW_SINGLE 1
| #define BENCHFFT_SINGLE 1
| #define HAVE_NEON 1
| #define WITH_SLOW_TIMER 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4223: error: in `/home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4':
configure:4225: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp'
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-arch=native
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='- L/usr/local/include'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='- L/usr/local/lib'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_MPICC_set=
ac_cv_env_MPICC_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-linux-gnueabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_CC='arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp'
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/missing aclocal-1.14'
ALLOCA=''
ALTIVEC_CFLAGS=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/missing automake-1.14'
AVX_CFLAGS=''
AWK='mawk'
CC='arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-arch=native'
CHECK_PL_OPTS=''
COMBINED_THREADS_FALSE=''
COMBINED_THREADS_TRUE=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='- L/usr/local/include'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
C_FFTW_R2R_KIND=''
C_MPI_FINT=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F77=''
FFLAGS=''
FGREP=''
FLIBS=''
GREP=''
HAVE_ALTIVEC_FALSE=''
HAVE_ALTIVEC_TRUE='#'
HAVE_AVX_FALSE=''
HAVE_AVX_TRUE='#'
HAVE_NEON_FALSE='#'
HAVE_NEON_TRUE=''
HAVE_SSE2_FALSE=''
HAVE_SSE2_TRUE='#'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='- L/usr/local/lib'
LDOUBLE_FALSE=''
LDOUBLE_TRUE='#'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBQUADMATH=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
MPICC=''
MPILIBS=''
MPIRUN=''
MPI_FALSE=''
MPI_TRUE=''
NEON_CFLAGS=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OCAMLBUILD=''
OPENMP_CFLAGS=''
OPENMP_FALSE=''
OPENMP_TRUE=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='fftw'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='fftw@fftw.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='fftw'
PACKAGE_STRING='fftw 3.3.4'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='fftw'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.3.4'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
POW_LIB=''
PRECISION='s'
PREC_SUFFIX='f'
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
QUAD_FALSE=''
QUAD_TRUE='#'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHARED_VERSION_INFO='7:4:4'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SINGLE_FALSE='#'
SINGLE_TRUE=''
SMP_FALSE=''
SMP_TRUE=''
SSE2_CFLAGS=''
STACK_ALIGN_CFLAGS=''
STRIP='arm-linux-gnueabi-strip'
THREADLIBS=''
THREADS_FALSE=''
THREADS_TRUE=''
VERSION='3.3.4'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_ct_F77=''
acx_pthread_config=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi'
host_alias='arm-linux-gnueabi'
host_cpu='arm'
host_os='linux-gnueabi'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/junaids/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "fftw"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fftw"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.4"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "fftw 3.3.4"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "fftw@fftw.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "fftw"
#define VERSION "3.3.4"
#define FFTW_ENABLE_ALLOCA 1
#define FFTW_SINGLE 1
#define BENCHFFT_SINGLE 1
#define HAVE_NEON 1
#define WITH_SLOW_TIMER 1

configure: exit 77
```

Kindly help if you can see what is wrong in config.log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM compiler with autoconf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188228/arm-compiler-with-autoconf); see the advice about reading a 'config.log'.  The error is some ways back for some reason you have '- L/usr/local/lib' with a **space** before the 'L'.  Perhaps your `env`ironment has some weird variable.  Also you could try to regenerate the autoconf variables.

Comment: Note particularly the `ac_cv_env_{C,CPP,LD}FLAGS_set=set` lines indicating what's been picked up from your environment. It seems somewhat ironic that the one environment variable which really _does_ deserve to be overridden appropriately - i.e. putting the `-march` and `-mfloat-abi` options in $CFLAGS (and possibly $LDFLAGS too if multilib is involved) where one would expect them - has been overlooked in favour of dicking about with $CC...